# Blockchain.com wallet was compromised and btc stelon

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I lost some money in a ico scam and googled and found a reclainfund ltd to recover fund. They ask me to  set up a blockchain.com account and then share account wallet id and password so they can transfer stolen fund. I did that. then I transferred 0.51 btc to my account and then changed my password.  now it seems to be hacked and my btc is gone and all transaction history is gone.  The weird thing is the blockchain's account left panel is totally empty now once I login and I can't see any transactions. how could that happen ? I wonder if someone inside blockchain.com is associated with hacker or scammer. that is really some high level scam I have ever see.

my question is in my blockchain.com account, where is the private key that they can steal and copy and it can bypass my changed password ?

Answer (score 1):

They only needed to have access to your account a single time to have exported your private key, then that wallet is compromised for good. Your password encrypts the private key as stored on Blockchain.com's server (so that Blockchain.com can't read the key) but it doesn't change the private key itself.

Comment: but how come I can't find my private key in blockchain.com web page ? maybe I am not bitcoin expert and not familiar with blockchain.com. I only see my wallet id and addresses. Secondly, how come my account page is totally broken and nothing is showing and all transaction history is gone.

Comment: It's there, it's might also be called a recovery phrase or under a "backup/export wallet" option.

Comment: what is the best way to try to recover fund ? to find a reclaim firm or report to police or FBI ? this is not trivial money.

Comment: You don't, unfortunately, it's gone for good. There's no way to reverse a Bitcoin transaction, even if it is a scam.

Comment: in my case, I contact the guy through this website. https://www.regaincrypto.com/ they sent me a investigation CASE number and a whatsapp contact number for me to chat. if this turns out to be a fraud, I would talk to police and FBI to trace down the website owner right ? I have all the communication email and chat history.

Comment: @raymondli: regaincrypto.com was registered only a few months ago. If you [check the address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/W+Watkins+St,+Oxford,+NC+27565,+USA) on their website it is a poor rural residential area. Also compare https://regaincrypto.com/Our-team/ with https://www.coinfirm.com/about-us/ - same photos, different names. scammers copy other scammers. You've probably been scammed at least three times here and need to be very careful.

Comment: If there was no withdrawal but export of the wallet then I assume you can still see in your local wallet or at blockchain.com the deposit address where you sent the 0.51 BTC to. If you post or PM this address / transaction I can have a look into with analytic tools if I can trace it already to an exchange. In case of success you could go with this information to police.

Comment: Even if you traced it to an exchange there's not very much they can do. The police probably won't take the case, and even if they did, and you did somehow find the recipient of the Bitcoin (which is unlikely) there's no way you can prove this particular transaction is a result of a scam and there's no way you can prove that particular recipient was the scammer.

Comment: It's a bit like if someone steals $5000 in cash from myself. I can report it to police and make a statement even if I cannot 100% prove that it was stolen. If 5 people report similar things then the police would ask the accused fraudster where he has all the money from. 
With bitcoin this would be similar if a scammer cheats a bunch of people and the transactions can be traced to a cash out and the receiver cannot explain where he had the coins from or why the people paid him in bitcoin. I'm not saying it's easy but possible if the involved jurisdictions are cooperating.

Comment: Dunno what jurisdiction you're in but having actually tried to report cash and valuables stolen myself, unless there is evidence such as a break-in, they will usually tell you to go away because it's almost impossible to prove.